# How do I specify that a workspace member should only be built on specific platforms?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a Cargo project with several workspaces:

```
[workspace]
members = [
    "crate-a", # Compiles on Linux
    "crate-b", # Compiles on Windows, Linux, Mac
]
```

How do I ensure that `crate-a` is disabled when building the project (i.e. running `cargo build`) on a Windows or Mac system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [no support in Cargo for this yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/5220).

You'll need to annotate all the methods, modules, etc. in `crate-a` with appropriate `#![cfg(target_os)]` attributes for now.